# Farkle Probability of rolling 1 or 5 on at least one die with x number of dice

Tags: probability, dice

So I was playing this game with my family, its called farkle. I don't really need to get into the rules of the game but the gist is you need to roll a 1 or a 5 with a die to score. I was thinking about this and wondering what the chances are of rolling a 1 or a 5 with x amount of dice. I thought, well the probability of rolling a 1 or 5 on one die is 2/6, but then with 2 dice it is not 2/6. I don't know exactly why it isn't 2/6, it just feels like something isn't right because of the fact that you can roll a 1 or 5 on one die and not the other, and I wanted to know how this works. Can anyone please help me understand the mathematical relation between these probabilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each die has a $\frac 23$ chance not to show a $1$ or $5$.  If you have $x$ dice, the chance that none of them show $1$ or $5$ is $\left(\frac 23\right)^x$ by the multiplication principle.  The chance that you get at least one die showing $1$ or $5$ is then $1-\left(\frac 23\right)^x$

Comment: Thank you so much it finally clicked for me! I knew it had something to do with multiplication and tried to do (2/6)^x but that didn't work. Thank you!

Comment: One more question, why do you subtract from 1, I sort of understand that it has to do with getting that other part, the part that is and isn't not, but what exactly is the purpose?

Comment: You either get a $1$ or $5$ or you do not and you can't do both, so the probabilities must sum to $1$.  The purpose is to show how the chance of getting at least one increases with $x$.  You know if you roll lots of dice it is (almost a) certainty you will get at least one $1$ or $5$.  This shows how close you are depending on $x$.

Comment: Okay, thank you!